# Cannot run `setup.py build` for mpi4py using PyPy

Tags: python, openmpi, pypy, mpi4py

I've been using the mpi4py library with OpenMPI to develop distributed memory programs.  So far, I've just been using vanilla Python 2.7 (CPython).

According to the [mpi4py project page](https://bitbucket.org/mpi4py/mpi4py), mpi4py is compatible with "PyPy 2.0 and above".

On my installation of Fedora 22, I installed PyPy 2.4.0 with:

`sudo dnf install pypy pypy-devel`

Then I created a virtualenv and activated it with:

`virtualenv env -p $(which pypy) && . env/bin/activate`

I then tried to install mpi4py with pip:

`pip install mpi4py`

But I get the following error:

```
...
File "conf/mpidistutils.py", line 121, in customize_compiler
   cxx = cxx .replace('-pthread', '')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

However, this same set of steps works just fine when using regular CPython.  I'm not terribly familiar with the nuances of PyPy; am I missing something obvious here?

(Note:  I already had installed OpenMPI with `sudo dnf -y install openmpi openmpi-devel` on F22)

Comment: you would be much better off asking the mpi4py devs. Chances are those are distutils problems that are fixed with a newer pypy, but I don't know for sure and it looks like the crash is somewhere inside mpi version of distutils